# How to create array of strings with numbers prefixed with zeros? (derp01,derp02,derp03)

Tags: ruby

Is there a more ruby way I can do this (less lines and easy to read):

```
derpNum = 20
derpNames = Array.new
derpNum.times do |derp|
  if derp < 10
    derpNames << "derp0#{derp}"
  else
    derpNames << "derp#{derp}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(1..20).map{|i| 'derp' + i.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}
```

or

```
(1..20).map{|i| 'derp%02d' % i}
```

`%02d` is a placeholder, which should be replaced with a 2-digit number, prefixed by `0` if it is not long enough.

Comment: damn thats awesome, what is the percent sign doing(how it is not padding zeros after it gets to 9)? what is that called in ruby so i can google it?

Comment: This is equivalent to `String.format("derp%02d", i)` in Java, or `sprintf("derp%02d", i)` in C.

Comment: For ruby documentation, see [this](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25)

Comment: hmm I tried doing this with a var instead and didn't work. EX: `var = 10; var.map{...`

Comment: Added some explanation about the `%02d` part.

Comment: @red888 The method `map` comes from the module `Enumerable`. A `Fixnum` (10) certainly is not an `Enumerable`.

Comment: Ah var.times.map{} does waht i want

Answer (score 2):

you may try this:

`(1..20).map { |i| i > 9 ? i.to_s : "0#{i}" }`

Comment: sorry maybe wasn't clear, the array will contain strings ex: derp01,derp02,etc- I'd need so if condition for this example to work (after it gets past 9

Comment: `(1..20).map { |i| prefix = i > 9 ? '' : "0"; "derp#{prefix}#{i}" }`

Comment: @Aetherus provided a nicer approach with rjust - I would recommend using it

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
collection    = []
collection[0] = 'derp01'

19.times {|index| collection.push(collection.last.next)}

# Output
 => collection
 => ["derp01", "derp02", "derp03", "derp04", "derp05", "derp06", "derp07", "derp08", "derp09", "derp10", "derp11", "derp12", "derp13", "derp14", "derp15", "derp16", "derp17", "derp18", "derp19", "derp20"]
```

See [this link](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) for `next` in `Enumerable` Module